# Сортировка списка в парсере

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Пишу парсер, который собирает информацию о валютах вот с этого сайта - https://www.banki.ru/products/currency/cb/

В процессе я все таки смог извлечь данные о валютах, однако возникли проблемы с сортировкой, вот полный код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = 'https://www.banki.ru/products/currency/cb/'

req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, features='html.parser')

cost = soup.find_all('tr')


def clean(obj):
    t = []
    for i in obj:
        t.append(re.sub('[\t\n]', '', i.text))
    return t


print(clean(cost))
```

На выходе я получаю список со всеми валютами и их атрибутами, однако в не совсем удобном виде, мне требуется:

1. Отсортировать список, чтобы в нем остались только элементы, начинающиеся с трех заглавных букв
2. Создать текстовый файл со значениями вида <Название валюты> <Код> <Цена> <Изменение цены>

Можете внести какие то улучшения в код в плане самого парсинга, так как это мой первый опыт работы с `bs4`, регулярными выражениями и `html` в целом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше парсером вытаскивать нужные поля, тогда не придется делать пост-обработку.

Кст:

- Метод `select` принимает `css-селектор`
- А выражение `tbody > tr[data-currency-code]` означает поиск всех `tr`, имеющих атрибут `data-currency-code` и у которых в родителях тег `tbody`

Попробуйте:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.banki.ru/products/currency/cb/'

rs = requests.get(url)
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

for tr in root.select('tbody > tr[data-currency-code]'):
    td_items = tr.select('td')
    code, num, name, value, change = \
        map(lambda x: x.get_text(strip=True), td_items)
    print(code, num, name, value, change)
```

Результат:

```
USD 1 Доллар США 73.4261 +0,0628
EUR 1 Евро 87.2889 +1,0357
AUD 1 Австралийский доллар 52.8154 +0,4633
...
ZAR 10 Южноафриканский рэнд 43.4922 -0,2144
JPY 100 Японская иена 70.1870 +0,3803
```

---

А чтобы это выгрузить в файл, предлагаю использовать `csv`.

Пример:

```
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://www.banki.ru/products/currency/cb/'

rs = requests.get(url)
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

with open('currency.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['<Название валюты>', '<Код>', '<Цена>', '<Изменение цены>'])

    for tr in root.select('tbody > tr[data-currency-code]'):
        td_items = tr.select('td')
        code, num, name, value, change = \
            map(lambda x: x.get_text(strip=True), td_items)
    
        writer.writerow([name, code, value, change])
```

Получится файл:

```
<Название валюты>,<Код>,<Цена>,<Изменение цены>
Доллар США,USD,73.4261,"+0,0628"
Евро,EUR,87.2889,"+1,0357"
Австралийский доллар,AUD,52.8154,"+0,4633"
Азербайджанский манат,AZN,43.2172,"+0,0369"
Армянский драм,AMD,15.0958,"-0,0494"
Белорусский рубль,BYN,30.0890,"+0,0073"
...
```